# VBA ActiveDocument.Range.Text in Unicode

Tags: regex, vba, unicode

In VBA (Word specifically), I'm trying to use the RegExp object to search through a long document. Some of the patterns I search for include unicode character (such as a non-breaking hyphen or non-breaking space). When I access the text via

```
ActiveDocument.Range.Text
```

I get the text but stripped of unicode characters (or at least some of them, ones that I need). For example, if the text `ABC-123`, where the hyphen is a non-breaking (or hard) hyphen, U+2011, when I access the text using `ActiveDocument.Range.Text`, it displays `ABC123`.

I thought perhaps it just displays it incorrectly, and that the character is really there, but all the search and replace I've done don't show it. Plus, when I regex the unicode character using `\u2011`, it doesn't find it.

Is there another way to access the document's full content, but intact with all the unicode characters?

**UPDATE:** I inspected the output of the `ABC123`, and it appears that the character is hidden. That is, `Len(str) = 7` instead of `6`, what you'd expect. The following shows what is happening:

```
Print Asc(Mid(str, 4, 1))
=> 30
```

ASCII character 30, or `\u001e` is a record separator. When I search for this, it finds this zero-length character. I tested a wider range of unicode characters (\u2000-\u201f) and interestingly they all are detected with the `\u` control sequence in the regex, **except** for `\u2011`, which changes to `\u001e`. Even the en-space (`\u2002`) and em-space (`\u2003`) are recognized. I haven't done it for all the unicode characters, but it seems odd that I have stumbled upon one of the few that don't register.

Comment: Have you tried using the open xml sdk and use `Body.InnerText` to get the full text of the document?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer, but a workaround. When using RegExp to search for unicode characters, most will be recognized in the `ActiveDocument.Range.Text` variable using a `\uxxxx` code. If not, open a new Word document. In the body, add some text that contains the unicode character (e.g. non-breaking hyphen). Then in VBA, use the immediates window to find the ASCII character code for that character:

```
Print Asc(Mid(ActiveDocument.Range.Text, <char_position>, 1))
```

This will tell you if it is actually there (if the character doesn't show up in strings). The code you get won't actually work for every unicode character, since some of them are converted to ASCII characters (e.g. en-quad `\u2000` will return ASCII 32, space, when using the Asc() function on it. Luckily, you can regex `\u2000` and it will find it.).

For the non-breaking hyphen, the code that works with regex is `\u001e`.